# .htaccess mod_rewrite to a separate script if it ends with a string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a simple CMS that will rewrite `http://host/path/to/resource` to `http://host/cms/render.php/path/to/resource` (unless a file exists at that location, e.g. an image).

How can have it redirect to a different script if the request ends with a certain string? For example:

`http://localhost/path/to/resource` --> `cms/render.php/$1`

`http://localhost/path/to/resource.admin` --> `cms/admin.php/$1`

This is what I've tried, but I just get an internal server error:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} = ^(.*)\.admin$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/render.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the `mod_rewrite` syntax? Seems like - you haven't

Comment: Add a `RewriteRule` (with the same `RewriteCond`) _before_ the current rule, like `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.admin$ cms/admin.php/$1` OTOH

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It doesn't need to be a condition in this case:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.admin$ cms/admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/render.php/$1 [L]
```